# Настройка базы данных MySql для Common Lisp

Tags: mysql, lisp

Windows-7, SBCL 1.2.11 (X86-64)

Установил базу mysql, создал пользователя, дал все права. Создал таблицу вручную.
Теперь хочу соединиться. Использовал библиотеку "cl-dbi".

```
(defvar *connection*
  (connect :mysql
    :database-name "base"
    :username "user"
    :password "1234"))

(setq query (prepare *connection* "SELECT * FROM catalogs"))
```

Пока всё нормально, а теперь ошибка

```
(execute query)
  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Та же проблема с библиотекой "cl-mysql". Ошибка такая же.
Понимаю что дело не в библиотеках, а в базе. Но что именно?

Comment: может быть, проблема всё-таки в связке sbcl+ms/windows? https://code.google.com/p/lispbuilder/issues/detail?id=27 (там по ссылкам ещё стоит сходить)

Comment: может... устал я уже от этих несовместимостей. Что теперь с этим делать?

Comment: рассуждая абстрактно: если две сущности плохо совместимы, то можно попробовать заменить хотя бы одну из них на аналог. это я исхожу из предположения, что вы вряд ли будете отлавливать причину появления этой ошибки и исправлять код *sbcl* для *ms/windows*.

Comment: есть ещё вариант попробовать другую базу с другой библиотекой, я уже прицелился.

Comment: если верить баг-репорту, то с большой долей вероятности, рано или поздно вы опять можете столкнуться с той же несовместимостью.